# Query posts from different categories in multisite

Tags: posts, multisite, query

In my planed multisite installation, I want the members to be able to post in one of two different categories.
Members in A can post in 1. Members from B can post in 2. All members can comment everything.

Then, I plan to create a custom page template to the blogs index, and I hope to query all posts from members in 1 and 2, and display title and a minor excerpt (along with avatar image) in separate columns (widgets).

Is this possible? (I am not planning to use Buddypress).

Comment: What does Multisite has to do with this? Should the category limitation be a network feature?

Comment: Yes, the category limitation is supposed to be an important network feature.

Comment: Did you managed to do this? I want to show products of woocommerce on a single page of the main site too. Using multisite, please advise and thank you

Answer (score 0):

For restricting the categories, maybe the plugin [Restrict Categories](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/restrict-categories/) can help. But it doesn't have Multisite capabilities.
Take a look at the filter `list_terms_exclusions` that it uses in the `cat_filter` [function](http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/restrict-categories/tags/2.5/restrict-categories.php).

But [Role Scoper](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/role-scoper/) states that it has "Extensive WP-mu support". May be worth a try.

For the query part, take a look at this Q&A, [find a random blogid across my multisite network that has at least one post published](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/60401/12615).
Basically, you need the functions [`switch_to_blog`](http://codex.wordpress.org/WPMU_Functions/switch_to_blog) and [`restore_current_blog`](http://codex.wordpress.org/WPMU_Functions/restore_current_blog).